# UITextField in UITableViewCell breaks Cut/Copy/Paste options

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

A portion of my app has a UITableViewCell that contains a UITextView, which needs to be editable. Everything works properly (including resizing) except for the pasteboard. See: [Screenshot of a broken pasteboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRhgL.png)

Basically when the user taps on text in the UITextView and the first set of pasteboard options show (Select, Select All, Paste) they all work fine. When they choose to select text, then the Cut, Copy, Paste, Replace, Define, Share options are all out of whack. For example, when I try to hit 'Copy' it performs the Define action (in addition to highlighting an area beyond the bounds of the copy option).

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but the UITableView has selection disabled, and the containing UITableViewCell is a subclass that conforms to UITextViewDelegate, and I've implemented:

```
textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText
textViewDidChange
```

But these are specifically for adjusting the height of the cell when the UITextView expands and setting a limit for the number of characters. I haven't done anything specific to leverage the pasteboard, and I'm not sure what I need here. I put a UITextView in an empty project as a sanity check, and this all works fine when not in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Currently having the same issue 

Comment: @Nagra Sadly no. I feel like I've exhausted many possibilities, including making the cells editable, implementing the textView:willBeginEditing protocol methods, and a few other things I managed to scrape from Google... I've been working on this on and off, but still haven't found anything that works =(